# Self-contained reproducible example of Python IB API with asyncio

Tags: python, callback, python-asyncio, asynccallback, tws

The excellent [ib_insync](https://github.com/erdewit/ib_insync) provides a higher level synchronous interface to the asynchronous IB API using the built-in asyncio module. However, there are situations where one might prefer to avoid relying on 3rd party modules. My attempt is to provide to the community a self-contained reproducible example of how to use the native `ibapi` with the Python built-in `asyncio` module to handle callbacks. For example, let say that one wants to add a method to convert a vector of weights to an actual number of shares to be traded. This would require invoking `reqAccountSummary` (to check the amount of cash in the account) and `reqMktData` (to get a snapshot of market prices) within the same method and to wait for the callbacks, `accountSummaryEnd` and `tickSnapshotEnd` respectively.

It now follows a (simpler) example where I invoke `reqContractDetails` and wait for the callback `contractDetailsEnd` within the same method `runSyncContractReq`. The same logic can, in theory, be applied to all requests with an associated callback. Unfortunately, this is not quite working yet since the program "awaits" the future callback forever.

I hope that a member of the community could help to make the example to work correctly in order to help novices with `ibapi` and `asyncio` like me.

```
from ibapi.client import EClient
from ibapi.wrapper import EWrapper
from ibapi.contract import Contract
import asyncio


class TwsApp(EWrapper, EClient):
    def __init__(self):
        self._nextValidId = None
        EWrapper.__init__(self)
        EClient.__init__(self, wrapper=self)
        # self.future stores IDs associated with asyncio.Future() objects.
        self.future = dict()

    def get_nextValidId(self):
        """Returns a valid ID useful to send requests to TWS or place orders."""
        reqId = self._nextValidId
        self._nextValidId += 1
        return reqId

    def nextValidId(self, orderId: int):
        """This method receives valid OrderIds form TWS whenever calling
        self.run() or self.reqIds()."""
        self._nextValidId = orderId
        self.runSyncContractReq()

    async def reqContractDetails(self, reqId, contractDetails):
        print('reqContractDetails STARTED')
        super().reqContractDetails(reqId, contractDetails)
        print('reqContractDetails AWAITING for Future to be done.')
        await self.future[reqId]
        print('reqContractDetails AWAITED!')

    def contractDetails(self, reqId: int, contractDetails):
        print('contractDetails RECEIVED!')

    def contractDetailsEnd(self, reqId):
        print('contractDetailsEnd STARTED')
        self.future[reqId] = self.future[reqId].set_result('done')
        print('contractDetailsEnd FINISHED')

    def runSyncContractReq(self):
        # Prepare data.
        contract = Contract()
        contract.conId = 756733
        contract.exchange = 'SMART'
        idReq = self.get_nextValidId()

        # asyncio.
        self.future[idReq] = asyncio.Future()
        loop = asyncio.get_event_loop()
        print('Running asyncio.ensure_future')
        asyncio.ensure_future(self.reqContractDetails(idReq, contract))
        print('Running loop.run_until_complete')
        loop.run_until_complete(self.future[idReq])
        loop.close()


if __name__ == '__main__':
    app = TwsApp()
    app.connect(host='127.0.0.1', port=7497, clientId=0)
    app.run()

### OUTPUT
Running asyncio.ensure_future
Running loop.run_until_complete
reqContractDetails STARTED
reqContractDetails AWAITING for Future to be done.

# However, contract details are somehow returned once the application is stopped.
ERROR:root:ERROR -1 2104 Market data farm connection is OK:usfuture
ERROR:root:ERROR -1 2104 Market data farm connection is OK:afarm
ERROR:root:ERROR -1 2104 Market data farm connection is OK:usfarm
ERROR:root:ERROR -1 2106 HMDS data farm connection is OK:ushmds
contractDetails RECEIVED!
contractDetailsEnd STARTED
contractDetailsEnd FINISHED
```

Comment: It's not clear how you this code could work with asyncio. If you have `app.run()`, it means that the asyncio event loop is simply not running. Ideally one would hook the asyncio event loop into the `ibapi` event loop or the other way around, but that is fairly involved. A more realistic option is to run `TwsApp` in a separate thread, and use `call_later_threadsafe` and similar primitives to schedule the corresponding coroutines on the asyncio level.

Comment: I came across your comment today. Putting TwsApp in a separate thread and running asyncio loop in a different one did the trick.